# How to update the configuration of an apache nifi processor without stopping it?

Tags: apache-nifi

Good morning, I'm using Apache Nifi, I wonder if anyone knows any way to change the setting of a processor without having to stop it. Or some viable alternative to prevent the loss of information.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The configuration of a processor cannot be changed while the processor is running and this is done intentionally. This provides guarantees to the developer of a processor so that in the onTrigger method they can be guaranteed all the properties have the same values that passed validation when the processor was started.

If you can describe your use-case more we might be able to come up with alternative approaches.

Answer (score 0):

there is an alternative solution. Duplicate the processor will update its configuration to the desired one. the output of the duplicate is connected to the next processor. the original processor is stopped and its queued connected to the duplicate and then turned on.

In one way or another the data flow has to be interrupted, but in this way the changes that take more time to make in the processor, can be made in the duplicate first, in order to reduce the impact of the interruption as much as possible.

regards